# how to get Accurate decimal equations using instance attributes?

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point

I have a project I'm working on where I have statistics that affect other statistics that is run through a premade mathematical formula, most of it works fine but i'm concerned about the float function's imprecision.

I have tried using the Decimal module but it doesn't seem like it will work with my attributes exampled below:

```
player.physical = 20
player.bodystatper = 45
player.truebody = float(player.bodystatper * (player.physical / 10))
```

now that player.truebody number may go into another formula with something else ect ect.

I know the decimal module requires numbers to be input like this: Decimal('4.5') to work properly but it messes with the attributes when I do so, really my question is if I can even use the Decimal module like this and if not is there another solution or will float not affect me as much as im afraid it will

Comment: "I know the decimal module requires numbers to be input like this: Decimal('4.5') to work properly but it messes with the attributes when I do so" - could you be more specific about what this "messes with"? It's not clear how instance attributes are in any way relevant.

Comment: (Also, note that `decimal.Decimal` isn't exact. It's just decimal. Numbers that cannot be exactly represented in decimal will still suffer precision loss.)

Comment: by messes with I mean I get an error (TypeError: 'module' object is not callable), I don't know what you mean by exactly represented but im mostly concerned with decimal multipliers I will be using getting screwed up (if I want to to add 0.1 and 0.2 then use the result to multiply against a different number I want that result to be 0.3 not 3.0000000000000004.

Comment: "by messes with I mean that it's changing it from an attribute to a string like quotation marks usually do" - what, are you setting `player.physical = '20'`? If you want to use Decimal math, you should set the attributes to actual Decimal instances, `player.physical = Decimal('20')`.

Comment: I thought of that but when I do the attribute formula how do I maintain the decimal numbers because it wont let me 
-
    player.truebody = Decimal ('player.bodystatper') * (Decimal ('player.physical') / 10)

Comment: That's not how this works. You should create the `Decimal` instances from the start, when you're setting the attributes in the first place. `player.physical = Decimal('20')`, like I said earlier. After that, `player.physical` is already a `Decimal` instance, and you don't need to call `Decimal` on it again.

Comment: see that's what I wasn't clear on, that's perfect then, thank you.